# CGI-image from Javascript in UIWebView Xcode

Tags: javascript, objective-c, uiwebview, cgimage

my problem is this - I have a UIWebView, which loads a local html file. This html file is javascript, which refers to mimetex.cgi this site - http://planetcalc.ru/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi

Question - can I do to mimetex.cgi placed directly on the device, that is, the program worked without using the Internet.

P.S. I know that sort of mimetex.cgi opens only on the server, but it can have any way to open it, what some frameworks such as ...

Comment: Well, first you need to get the file. Can you get the file?

Comment: @Linuxios if you mean CGI file, here - http://planetcalc.ru/cgi-bin/mimetex.cgi

Comment: But that's not a download for the file. That's calling it. You need the file itself it you want to run it locally.

Comment: @Linuxios That is, you say that you can not just download the file and run it locally? Sorry, I'm just learning)))

Comment: The point is, the link you gave does not allow downloading the .cgi file. You need the file itself, or a way to download it if you want to run it locally.

Comment: @Linuxios this? - http://www.forkosh.com/mimetex.zip

Comment: I think so. That should be the right file.

Comment: @Linuxios I can run it in Xcode?

Comment: I don't know. I have to look at it. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run the code form MimeTeX in an Xcode project, as it is written in C using only basic C standard libraries. Just add them to the project and call their functions, are start it as a sub process using popen.